# How to make pyplot have evenly spread y ticks with values [0, 1/2, 3/4, 7/8, ...]

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis

I would like to compare a few algorithms by a graph of their convergence probability curves.

Currently, my graph looks as follows:

[image]

which does not allow to see the difference in many of the curves.

I want to have y axis to be "logarithmic", but in its difference from the value 1, i.e. I want the y values to be [0, 1/2, 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, ... 1023/1024], but so every tick would still have the same distance from the last (i.e., the distance from 1/2 to 3/4 is the same as the one from 15/16 to 31/32).

I've tried using the `yticks()` function, but it doesn't place the ticks evenly:

[image]

> **How do I make this axis look right?**

---

My current code:

```
def plotCDFs(CDFs, names = []):
   legend = []
   for i, CDF in enumerate(CDFs):
       keys = sorted(CDF)
       vals = sorted(CDF.values())
       plt.plot(keys,vals)
       legend.append(str(names[i]))
   plt.title('Cumulative Distribution')
   plt.legend(legend, loc='lower right')
   plt.xscale('log')
   plt.gca().set_ylim([0,1])
   #plt.yticks([1-2**-i for i in xrange(11)])
   plt.show()
```

Comment: Did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities: You can plot `1-cumulative Distribution` in an ordinary log-log plot which is what I usually do or you (probably) have to create your own log-plot as you describe above. At least I have never seen a builtin function which achieves this.

This code should work

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def ToLog(x):
    return 1.-np.log10(1.-x)

def plotCDFs(CDFs, names = []):
    legend = []
    max_vals = 0.0
    for i, CDF in enumerate(CDFs):
        keys = sorted(CDF)
        vals = sorted(CDF.values())
        if vals.max() > max_vals:
            max_vals = vals
        plt.plot(keys,ToLog(vals))
        legend.append(str(names[i]))
    plt.title('Cumulative Distribution')
    plt.legend(legend, loc='lower right')
    plt.xscale('log')

    # handling the yaxis ticks and ticklabels
    i_max = np.floor(np.log(1-max_vals.max())/np.log(2.))
    yticks = 1.-2.**np.linspace(i_max,0,-i_max+1)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_yticks(1.-np.log10(1.-yticks))
    ax.set_yticklabels([str(i-1)+'/'+str(i) for i in 2**np.arange(-int(i_max),0,-1)])

    ax.set_ylim([0,1])
    plt.show()
```

Note that `ToLog` must be applied on all `ydata` before plotting.